# validar si una variable es de tipo fecha

Tags: php

lo que pasa es que estoy realizando una consulta a una base de datos IINFORMIX y el campo es de tipo DATETIME con Formato (year to fraction(3)) Aclaro que el formato no lo puedo modificar.

Actualmente yo tengo esta función:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'){
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
        return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

y realizo la validación de esta forma:

```
foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
    $array[$key1] =   ( validateDate($value1, 'Y-m-d H:i:s.v' ) == 1 )? conver_date($value1,'d-m-Y H:i:s') : $value1;
}
```

Pero no me funciona, la función sirve, el problema es el formato para validar la fecha, estaba revisando la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) pero no encuentro como, la fecha que viene de la base de datos es esta: 2017-06-28 10:33:31.033

Ahora si yo ejecuto

```
foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        $array[$key1] =   ( validateDate($value1, 'Y-m-d H:i:s.033' ) == 1 )? conver_date($value1,'d-m-Y H:i:s') : $value1;
    }
```

Me funciona pero solo con las fechas que terminen en .033

Comment: podrias aclarar que queres decir cuando decis que no funciona.. no la convierte? devuelve un error?

Comment: Cuando digo que no me funciona es que cuando realizo la validación, usando la función validateDate() el valor a retorna no es 1 (valor que devuelve cuando detecta que la variable es una fecha) , aclarando que el valor enviado si es una fecha. como la que puse en la pregunta. La razón por la cual no me realiza la validación es por el formato que le envió para validar, al no coincidir el formato de la fecha con el formato enviado para validar , por eso es que no me esta retornando de manera correcta, igual por lo pronto ps ya cambie mi función y ya solucione mi problema, de todas formas Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno ya lo resolví, dejo la respuesta en caso de que a alguien le pase lo mismo, modifique la función de validar si es fecha por la siguiente:

```
function validateDate($date){
        $d = strtotime($date);
        return ($d>=1) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Y la implementación quedo así:

```
( validateDate($value1) == 1 )? conver_date($value1,'d-m-Y H:i:s') : $value1;
```

Gracias de todas formas :)